gedit customisation via gsettings
I am trying to programmatically customise various settings in the gedit application, and currently I've got the following command to change the colour scheme.
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'cobalt' 

The issue I have is, if you see below, there are some colour schemes which are two words.

Now with that in mind, I've tried the following command, but with no success:
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'solarized dark'

Unfortunately, I do not get any errors or feedback to say the above command has not worked. Would anyone know what I have done wrong here?

Maybe '"Solarized Dark"' (double quotes inside single quotes)?

Thank you for your input @muru, I gave your suggestion a try, but no luck, unfortunately.

Then maybe solarized-dark? Seems to be the id according to this XML file in the source code

@muru That actually work and thanks a lot for your provided link.

With the assistance of @muru it turns out the right command to set either the Solarized Dark or Solarized Light colour scheme is as follows:
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'solarized-dark'
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'solarized-light'

The gnome documentation listed the colours scheme in the same manner, and this was the error in my original command.
Reference: gedit Schema

You can change the colorization directly within gedit using:  3bar (setup) --> preferences --> Fonts and Colors

Hello @tckosvic yes, I am aware that you can change these settings via the gedit GUI itself. I'm looking to automate steps like this via a script file to save time.
